# how to iterate json response to map json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular

How to iterate through json response to find `value`. I have this function `getObjects` to iterate through the response json `obj` and key which is the `swaggerDefSplit` (api/user).

```
getObjects(obj, key) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            var val = obj[i];
            objects.push(val);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}


getSwagger() {
    this._searchService.getSwagger()
        .subscribe(data => {
            // data = json response
            console.log(data.paths);
            let swaggerFullUrl = (<any>window).parent.swaggerURL;
            let hashSplit = swaggerFullUrl.split('#');
            let swaggerDefSplit = hashSplit[1].split('/');
            // debugger; 
            var exist = this.getObjects(data, "/api/"+swaggerDefSplit[1]);
            console.log(exist[4]);
        },
        err => {
            console.log('err', err);
        }

        );
}
```

This `console.log(exist[4]);` gives me every `api/paths` but what I'm expecting is to give me the `api/path` relative to my `swaggerSplit` say (user) for example instead of giving me every paths.

json response I get from the console.log:

```
/api/User:{} // map this instead of everything
/api/Items:{}
/api/Stocks:{}
```

Hope I'm making sense at all.

Comment: can you post json data?

Comment: add your json response. You might be getting the response in that way..

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha I have its under json response: above, I'm trying to map User:{..} Object as at the moment its just giving me everything.

Comment: @DeendayalGarg I have added it in my post.

Comment: Got it. The reason might be that your `getObject` is not returning anything. the console.log output that you see is for the first line `console.log(data.paths);` in subscribe method. can you print the `key` in `getObject`?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg No its not coming from the first `console.log` at all, the return objs are coming from the 2nd `console.log`

Comment: Can you `console.log` key inside `getObject`?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg Yeah that would only give me whatever is in my exist which is `"/api/"+swaggerDefSplit[1]`

Comment: that is strange. by looking at the above code thats the only things that can be figured out.